# Print line number incrementing with each input in C

Tags: c

I would like to see line number in the console when it asks for input.

Something like:

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
```

Here 1 was shown in the prompt and I enter any input and hit enter
Then the next number shows up and I do the same.

Any simple help for this in C for a beginner?

Comment: Have a counter variable and increment it with every input you ask for. You'll then print it explicitly with every new input, something like: `unsigned int n = 0; for(;;) { /*... */ printf("%u", ++n); /* read input */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will might help you.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int lineNo = 0;
    char name[256];

    do {
        printf("%d ", ++lineNo);
        scanf("%s", name);

    } while (strlen(name) > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should specify the max size of the string to input in `scanf` in the format string, otherwise it's no better than `gets`.

Comment: yes, scanf_s("%s", name, 256); is more stable.

Comment: both are the same "stable". One is not as safe as another

Comment: To read a _line_ of user input, best to use `fgets()`.

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is MSVC-specific stuff. You shouldn't include in a general answer, for instance it is entirely meaningless if using GCC.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", name);`   when the user enters nothing more than a <cr> the contents of `name` will not change. the result will be a 'forever' loop

Comment: I don't know <cr>. What is <cr>?

Comment: I certainly would but I don't have enough reputation (15).

Comment: I'd need 2 more. Its 13 now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I tried the easiest way I know for this. You can do this with the help of a 2D array. Following is the code for this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char arr[3][1];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<1;j++){
        printf("%d ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);
        }
}

}
```

You can change the size of the array as per the number of inputs you want. This code is taking 3 inputs, you can change it to as per your input needs.

Comment: `char arr[3][1];` is too small and leads to undefined behavior with `scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);`.  The application of `for(j=0;j<1;j++){` is amiss as no need to loop for each character.