# I was running my program and curious to understand the difference between these two?

Tags: c

Please help me understand this line and firstly I was using `getch()` but then I used `return(0)` and it shows this:

> Process returned 14 (0xE)   execution time : 0.015 s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return (c);
}

void main() {
    int x, y, z;
    x = 5;
    y = 10;
    z = add(x, y);
    printf("The sum is: %d", z);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: This code looks very **C**, and not very **C++**.  Given the `<conio.h>`, it also appears to be ancient, from the time neckbearded dinosaurs roamed the earth.

Comment: `main` function should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, please consider reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You are currently learning many poor habits

Comment: And there's no need for parentheses around the value you're returning. Nor in anything approaching modern C is there a need for separate declaration of variables and initialization.  `int a = 1;` vs. `int a; a = 1;' for instance.

Comment: True, I am learning Data Structure through C and C++, basic also new to stackoverflow so added the tag c++ for reach, hopefully I won't get extinct from this ecosystem at least.

Comment: What on earth does the basic and dsa tag do here? They are completely random.

Comment: There is a meta post on [C/C++ tagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags), and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045486/print-line-number-incrementing-with-each-input-in-c/68058865#68058865) related to the use of `getch()`, which might be useful reference for the future.

Comment: Also, it's useful to mention which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an `int` from main, but the return type is `void`.
Change the return type of main to `int`, you'll get 0 as the return value.

If you compile this with gcc in a file test.c, it will tell you, e.g.:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:19:7: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
   19 | return(0);
      |       ^
test.c:11:6: note: declared here
   11 | void main()
      |      ^~~~
```

Note that the `#include <conio.h>` has to be removed first to be compiled with *gcc*, since it is non-standard.